# XamComboBoxField in XamDataGrid is Empty

Tags: c#, wpf, xamdatagrid

Please help there is no data in the drop down in the combobox field in the xamdatagrid this only thing it show that it is a collection
[image]

I have this class

```
 public class AvisTIlGrid {
        public int BureaoOrdreNr { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        public int UgeavisID { get; set; }
        public string bureauOrdreNr { get; set; }

        public List<Fejl> fejl { get; set; }

}
```

```
public  class Fejl
    {
        private string fejltekst;

        public string FejlTekst { get => fejltekst; set => fejltekst = value; }
    }
```

And in a Dao Class the fejl is populated with data from the FejlTekstTable

```
fejl = diMPdot.tblFejlTeksts.Select( f => new Fejl()
                                               {
                                                   FejlTekst = f.FejlTekst
                                               }).ToList()
```

The result from the query looks like this its a List
Ingen valgt
Bestilt for sent - ikke bragt
Ordre ikke modtaget
Glemt annonce
DLU har fremsendt forkert matr.
Vi har indrykket forkert matr.
Forkert farve
Forkert placering
Forkert annonce format
Glemt farve

And in my view class I have a XamDataGrid where Specify a ComboBoxField but when I run the code there is no data in the dropdown memu

```
      <igWPF:ComboBoxField  Name="fejl" DisplayMemberPath="FejlTekst" Label="Fejl" >
                    </igWPF:ComboBoxField>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <igWPF:ComboBoxField Name="fejl" Label="Fejl" DisplayMemberPath="FejlTekst" ValuePath="FejlTekst" BindingType="Unbound" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <igWPF:ComboBoxField.Settings>
                        <igWPF:FieldSettings>
                            <igWPF:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type igWPF:XamComboEditor}">
                                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataItem.fejl}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </igWPF:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                        </igWPF:FieldSettings>
                    </igWPF:ComboBoxField.Settings>
                    </igWPF:ComboBoxField>
```